# Should it not be "all the" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Here's the following sentence I came across in a book:

**All members of this book series focus on modern-day problems.**

So, it might not be a serious issue, but I was taught that

-we use *all* if we refer to objects in general. For example, *all mammals have four legs.*

-we use *all the* if we refer to specific, exact objects. For example, *all the teachers in this school are amazing*  (--meaning that not all teachers are amazing in the whole world, but in this school every single one of them is.)

I found websites (and even a thread here ) which back up this rule:
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/all-members-of-vs-all-the-members-of.2961958/

[all + noun, all + the noun, all of the + noun, all of + noun, which one is right?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273466/all-noun-all-the-noun-all-of-the-noun-all-of-noun-which-one-is-right)

https://blog.esllibrary.com/2012/09/11/answering-students-grammar-questions-when-do-i-use-all-of-the-all-the-or-all/

So, with all this evidence that the correct usage of this structure is what i just wrote above, why is that sentence considered okay? If they're talking about that given book series, shouldn't it be *all the members of*?

Thank you everyone in advance :)

Comment: I prefer _All of this book series' members focus on modern-day problems._ It puts the active agent (members) next to its effective verb (focus) and it gives a substitute article (this) to cover both 'book series' and 'members' in definition. Plus it avoids the clumsiness of an absent article (all members) or an ellipsis ('all members' instead of 'all of the members').

Comment: Thank you Nigel J

Answer (score 1):

The sentences refer to “members of the book” or "teachers in this school", each of which is a noun phrase referring to a particular group. Dictionary.cambridge,org has *all* as a determiner, meaning “*every one (of), or the complete amount or number (of), or the whole*.

“*All members ...*” therefore describes adequately, concisely and correctly the relevant members (of the book). Similarly with "*All teachers ...*". As such, it is hard to see any need to use the longer and no more precise "*all the*".

A similar but not identical usage is in the long-used command on ships: "*All hands on deck!"* The relevant group is clearly defined.

I suggest a simple analysis is sometimes easier than seeking the specific application of complex general rules (this notion will attract adverse comment from some respondents, so do not accept my answer without considering them too).

Comment: The sentence actually refers not to "members of the book" but to "members of the book **series**". There is a difference.

Comment: Thanks. I imagined as much but we could replace "book" by "series" and still do the same analysis on "members of the series", so I ignored the possibility. Nevertheless I have agreed your comment by mark-up.

Comment: Thank you Anton and Robusto.